# Не срабатывает конструктор при создании массивов объектов Java

Tags: java, конструктор

Только начал изучать язык Java и наткнулся на проблему. При создании массивов объектов у меня почему-то не срабатывают конструкторы. Когда создаю один экземпляр объекта такой проблемы не нет.

Код:

```
public class fifth
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyClass[] object = new MyClass[6];
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    private int count;

    MyClass()
    {
        System.out.println("Class created!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приведённом вами коде вы не создали ни одного объекта класса `MyClass`. Вы создали массив, элементами которого **будут** шесть объектов класса `MyClass`. Чтобы конструктор сработал, вам понадобиться дополнить код:

```
public class Fifth {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyClass[] array = new MyClass[6];
        array[0] = new MyClass();
        array[1] = new MyClass();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нет простого способа без цикла создать объекты по каждому из указателей?

Comment: Самое простое - цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Он и не должен срабатывать.

И так везде с массивами указателей или ссылок (managed), а не только в Java.

Представьте, если у класса будет конструктор с параметрами. Что тогда должно произойти, по-вашему?

Comment: Как конструктор может не срабатывать если я создаю объект(ы) своего типа, которому я прописал конструктор. В С\С++ конструктор срабатывает всегда при создании объекта. В Java есть отличия? (Какие?, Почему в моей ситуации не сработало).

Comment: Сработает конструктор по-умолчанию(Тот что без параметров. У меня такой же в программе).

Comment: @St2211 Не объекты, а массив ссылок "предназначенных указывать на" объекты.

Comment: @St2211 А если нет конструктора по умолчанию?

Comment: Конструктор по умолчанию есть всегда, он создастся сам если его не прописал программист (Сужу по С\С++, с Java я только начал работать).
В чем проблема у меня я понял. Только мне не совсем понятно как по указателю который я объявил создать объекты. (Ответ уже дали)

Comment: @St2211 "Конструктор по умолчанию есть всегда, он создастся сам если его не прописал программист" Неверно.