# Двумерный Vector Java

Tags: java

```
        obj.vec = new Vector[5][3];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) 
                obj.vec[i][j].add(1);
```

В Java новичок, хочу обернуть двумерный массив в двумерный вектор, компилятор выдает ошибку, объясните в чем причина?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не срабатывает конструктор при создании массивов объектов Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/810989/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-java)

Comment: 1) Не совсем понятно, какую структуру данных вы хотите получить: двумерный массив чисел или двумерный массив векторов. Пока что больше похоже на второй вариант.

2) `Vector<E>` в Java является типизированным, поэтому если Вы хотите его заполнить целочисленными значениями, нужно задать тип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен вопрос и цель того, что вы делаете.
Могу предположить, что нужно:

```
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class VectorTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Vector<Integer[][]> vector = new Vector();
            vector.add(new Integer[5][3]);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    vector.get(0)[i][j] = new Random().nextInt();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Но практической пользы в этом не вижу.

Плюс ознакомьтесь с понятием конструктор в Java и приемы его использования.